# Transient fields change will affect entity manager

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

My process is as follows:

1. load entity from dao by entity manager
2. change something in fields that those fields is mark as `@Transient`
3. after finish process, I mean finish a transaction, I see some update statement log from JPA

Usually, I think problems as: when I get entity from entity manager, so em will put entity as state management, that why when I change fields it will flush to db when transaction end

my question is:

Does entity manager mark an Entity as changed when I change the value of a `@Transient` field in this entity?

Thanks!